# Strong Law of Large numbers for $f(Y, X_i)$ with everything independent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability, law-of-large-numbers

Assume $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ are i.i.d. random variables from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$. $Y$ is another random variable that is independent from the $X_i$. Does it hold that, almost surely

$$\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N f(Y, X_i) \to \mathbb{E}[f(Y, X_1) | Y].$$
For a specific value $y$, we have that by the law of large numbers

$$\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N f(y, X_i) \to \mathbb{E}_{X_1}[f(y, X_1)]$$

almost surely. But since there are uncountably many values $y$ that $Y$ can take, this is not enough. I can assume that $f$ is sufficiently nice.

Comment: Look at Theorem 4.2 in [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268048056_Conditional_strong_law_of_large_number).

Comment: I think the ergodic theorem (such as Birkhoff–Khinchin theorem) applied to the measure-preserving shift $\theta((Y,X_n)_{n\geq1})=(Y,X_{n+1})_{n\geq1}$ would prove the claim, although I suspect a much elementary solution is available by taking advantage of the conditional i.i.d. structure.

Comment: I think Fubini's theorem should be enough.

Comment: @SangchulLee yes I also just found out about the ergodic theorem, I think that will work. Thanks